# Using a nested type as a generic type argument in the enclosing class' supertype declaration

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

I basically have a question about why the following does not work.  I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Abstrct <T> {

}
```

I then define a class that makes use of that class with a public inner class defined that I want to use for the generic parameter, as follows:

```
public class Outer extends Abstrct<Inner> {
    public class Inner {

    }
}
```

As I am learning Java still, I am more interested in why it does not work.  Not so much as to how to make it work, but I would be interested in that also.

Answer (score 18):

`Inner` is not in scope for the class declaration of `Outer`. It's not a known type name when used in the `extends` clause. Use a qualified reference:

```
class Outer extends Abstract<Outer.Inner>
```

Or import it:

```
import com.example.Outer.Inner;
```

From the specification, regarding [Scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a declaration of a member `m` declared in or inherited by a
>   class type `C` (§8.1.6) is **the entire body of `C`**, including any nested
>   type declarations.

The `extends` clause is part of the class' `Superclass` declaration, as described in the [Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1). It's not part of the class body.

The scope of a type used in an `import` statement, however,

> [..] **is all the
>   class and interface type declarations (§7.6) in the compilation unit
>   in which the import declaration appears**, as well as any annotations on
>   the package declaration (if any) of the compilation unit .

Comment: Or simply declare `public class Outer extends Abstract<Outer.Inner>`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Abstrct<Outer.Inner>` making the type unambiguous and valid.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be explicit since the inner class you defined is not static so it only exists within the scope of the containing class.  (See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

In your case try following:

```
public class Outer extends Abstrct<Outer.Inner> {
    public class Inner {

    }
}
```

Comment: Even if it was static, they'd still need to import it or use a qualified type name.